# Django Python, Como desabilitar el botón, cuando se presiona por primera vez o N cantidades de veces?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, django

Me ayudan, ¿Existe algún método javascript u otro para que el usuario no presione x cantidad de veces el botón guardar de un formulario?
en Django ocurre que al presionar x cantidad de veces, cuando completo el formulario da el siguiente error, no tengo nada de Javascript, estoy buscando un método, me pueden ayudar.

````
<!-- Save Evento-->
            <form action="{% url 'save_evento' interno=bus.interno %}" id="guardar_evento" method="post"
                enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="container ">
                    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center transparent_background_detalle_interno">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-10">
                                    <h3 class="partes_seleccionadas">TABLA</h3>
                                    <input type="tel" class="border rounded border-primary form-control" id="tabla_reg"
                                        placeholder="Ingrese la Tabla" minlength="2" maxlength="8" 
                                        name="tabla" value="{{tabla_ret}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-10">
                                    <h3 class="partes_seleccionadas" name="avtivo">CÓDIGO OB </h3>
                                    <input type="tel" class="border rounded border-primary form-control" id="tabla_cod"
                                        placeholder="Código" minlength="1" maxlength="4" 
                                        name="cod_operador" value="{{codigo_ret}}">
                                    <button class="btn btn-info conducor_btn waves-effect waves-light col-7 btn_buscar_conductor"
                                     onclick="searchConductor()" type="button" id="btn_buscar_conductor">Buscar Conductor</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-10">
                                    <h3 class="partes_seleccionadas">RESPONSABILIDAD</h3>
                                    <select class="bg-warning form-control form-control" id="select_responsabilidad"
                                        name="responsabilidad" required>
                                        <option value="" {% if responsabilidad_ret == "" %}selected{% endif %} disabled>
                                            Seleccione una responsabilidad
                                        </option>

                                        <option value="O" {% if responsabilidad_ret == "O" %}selected{% endif %}>
                                            Operaciones
                                        </option>

                                        <option value="V" {% if responsabilidad_ret == "V" %}selected{% endif %}>
                                            Vandalismo
                                        </option>

                                        <option value="M" {% if responsabilidad_ret == "M" %}selected{% endif %}>
                                            Mantenimiento
                                        </option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
</form>
```
```
Views.

@login_required(login_url="iniciar_sesion")
def save_evento(request, interno):
    params = Parameters(request)

    if request.POST:
        responsabilidad = request.POST.get('responsabilidad')
        cod_operador = request.POST.get('cod_operador')

        

        conductor = None
        try:
            if cod_operador ==  "":
                cod_operador = 0000
            conductor = models.Conductor.objects.get(cod_operador=cod_operador)
            rut_input_conductor = None
        except ObjectDoesNotExist as NotFound:
            conductor = None
            rut_input_conductor = request.POST.get('rut_input_conductor')

        

        tabla = request.POST.get('tabla_reg')
        graffiti = False

        if responsabilidad == 'V':
            if request.POST.get('graffiti'):
                graffiti = True
        
        linea = request.POST.get('tabla_linea')
        observacion = request.POST.get('observacion')

        evento = models.Evento(
                responsabilidad=responsabilidad,
                cod_operador=cod_operador,
                conductor=conductor,
                sin_codigo=rut_input_conductor,
                tabla=tabla,
                usuario=params.getUsuario(),
                bus=models.Bus.objects.get(interno=interno),
                patio=params.getUsuario().patio,
                recorrido=linea,
                graffiti=graffiti
                )

        if evento.save():
            print('Evento Guardado Con Exito..!')
        dano = models.Dano(evento=evento, observacion=observacion)
        if dano.save():
            print('Daño guardado!')

        if request.FILES.get('foto1'):
            models.FotoDano(foto=request.FILES.get('foto1'), dano=dano).save()
            print("Foto 1 guardada para evento: " + str(dano.evento.id))
        
        if request.FILES.get('foto2'):
            models.FotoDano(foto=request.FILES.get('foto2'), dano=dano).save()
            print("Foto 2 guardada para evento: " + str(dano.evento.id))

        if request.FILES.get('foto3'):
            models.FotoDano(foto=request.FILES.get('foto3'), dano=dano).save()
            print("Foto 3 guardada para evento: " + str(dano.evento.id))

        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Ha sido añadido un evento con identificador: ' + str(evento.id))
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'NO SE AGREGO EVENTO.. Ocurrio un problema Interno...')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('buscar_interno'))
````

Este es el error, cuando presiono N veces el boton Guardar, me aparece ese error, me imagino que debe ser por presionar muchas veces el boton como modo de prueba, sigo buscando una manera en Javascript, para que el envío se realice una sola vez.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Claro que hay forma, pero debes agregar el código mínimo necesario y mostrar además que has hecho

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Sip, ya subi parte de la vista html y view completa, que ocupo.